# How to log into a file in Undertow embedded server?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, undertow

I have simple example, where I implement an access log handler. It does log to a console. How to configure the logger to log to a specified file?

```
package com.zetcode;

import io.undertow.Undertow;
import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.AccessLogHandler;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver;
import io.undertow.util.Headers;

class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) {

        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello there");
    }
}

public class UndertowLogEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
                .setHandler(new AccessLogHandler(new MyHandler(), new JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver(),
                        "combined", UndertowLogEx.class.getClassLoader()))
                .build();

        server.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver` logs access logs to the jboss-logging facade. The jboss-logging facade will log to whichever log manager you have configured. If you've got a console handler configured, it would log to the console.

If you'd like to log to a file you could use the `DefaultAccessLogReceiver`.

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
DefaultAccessLogReceiver.Builder builder = DefaultAccessLogReceiver.builder().setLogWriteExecutor(executor)
        .setOutputDirectory(Paths.get("/var/log/undertow"))
        .setLogBaseName("access-log.")
        .setLogNameSuffix("log")
        .setRotate(true);   

Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
    .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
    .setHandler(new AccessLogHandler(new MyHandler(), builder.build(),
            "combined", UndertowUrlRewrite.class.getClassLoader()))
    .build();

server.start();
```

Comment: The log manager of the mentioned is configured with `logging.properties`? (embedded usage).

Comment: Ah. So if you want to have it go through jboss-logging you could add a FileHandler. Using the option above though gives a bit cleaner of a log file. Easier to parse anyway :)

Comment: I like the example you provided. It is good for demonstration. I want this for teaching/learning purposes. I found about the FileHandler but failed to find some doc to implement it; only this, but is uses console: https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/examples/src/main/resources/logging.properties

Comment: WildFly has an example of a `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` if you're interested https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/9.0.2.Final/core-feature-pack/src/main/resources/content/standalone/configuration/logging.properties#L48-L56. I could also give you more logging.properties examples if needed :)

Comment: Hi, I did something like the same code in avobe. My server is running without problem but couldn't get any log in my log file.  The difference is I used HttpHandler is this way HttpHandler next = path()
                    .addPrefixPath(REST_OBJECT_PREFIX, Handlers.routing()
                    .........
Do you have idea why I do not get any log in the log file?